# Informix: differences between two similar tables?

Tags: sql, informix

I need to generate a report when I come across any differences in data in two almost identical tables. (I'm using Informix database Version 11.70.)

For instance: my live table has columns:

Live

```
Name    ID  TRN  
XXX      1   10
```

Archive:

```
Date        Name   ID   TRN  
01/01/2018  XXX    1    10  
31/12/2017  XXX    1    11  
29/12/2017  XXX    1    12
```

The Archive table has the same set of columns except that it also has a date column so I can see what values the live table had at a given date.

How would I write a query to find if there was change of values in live data when compared with the archived data.

I tried this query:

```
select name,id,TRN from live
union
select name,id,TRN from archive
```

Though it works, is there a better/faster way around as in report I need to have both live data and difference in historic values.

Expected results in report:

```
Live:
01/01/2018|XXX|1|10  
Archive
31/12/2017|XXX|1|11  
29/12/2017|XXX|1|12
```

Comment: Your sample query doesn't include the date fields; your expected output does.  That's a conceptual disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider:

```
SELECT "Live" AS source, a.date, a.name, a.id, a.trn
  FROM archive AS a JOIN live AS l
    ON a.name = l.name AND a.id = l.id AND a.trn = l.trn
UNION  ALL
SELECT "Archive" AS source, a.date, a.name, a.id, a.trn
  FROM archive AS a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT * FROM live AS l
        WHERE a.name = l.name AND a.id = l.id AND a.trn = l.trn
       )
```

This shows a row from Archive that matches each row in Live, and also
shows each row in Archive without a direct match in Live.  If you think you might have rows in Live that have no corresponding row in Archive, you'd need another term in your union, such as:

```
SELECT "Unarchived" AS source, NULL::DATE AS date, l.name, l.id, l.trn
  FROM live AS l
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT * FROM archive AS a
        WHERE l.name = a.name AND l.id = a.id AND l.trn = a.trn
       )
```

This selects those rows in Live that have no matching row in Archive.  If you prefer, you can use `TODAY` or `TODAY ± 1` (or some such expression) in place of `NULL::DATE`, depending on your requirements.

<sup>*Warning: untested SQL — there could be bugs in it!*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select name,id,TRN from live
minus
select name,id,TRN from archive
```

to find rows in live that are not in archive, and

```
select name,id,TRN from archive
minus
select name,id,TRN from live
```

to find rows in archive that are not in live.

Comment: Sorry, I checked it in version 12.

Comment: Sorry for the brief reply; I've got some other tasks going on this afternoon.  Without "minus" our options are "not in" or outer join.  "Minus" compares nulls as well as data, the other two don't.  There are ways of dealing with that, but not as clean.  Are any of these columns constrained to be "not null", because that would help.  How many rows are you dealing with?